# Display ReportViewer results on Load - ServerReport.Refresh() doesn't do anything

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

I have a `ReportViewer` control on my webpage. It loads properly and when I click on the "View Report" button, the results are properly displayed.

But now I want it to display the results when the page loads and not ask the user to click on the "View Report" button.

I see everywhere that I must use the `ServerReport.Refresh()` method, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I subscribed to the `ReportRefresh` event, it's not even fired.

The control is on a "regular" page, nothing else on it, no UpdatePanel.
I added a button that also executes `ServerReport.Refresh()` but it doesn't work either, nothing happens.
I tried to enable/disable most options that seem to relate to the issue (`ShowRefreshButton`, `AsyncRendering`...) and I've set all the parameters.

I also tried to put the initialization code in the `Page_Init()` method, without success.

The report won't load without clicking on the "View Report" button.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Sets credentials, URL & Path
        ReportHelper.InitializeReportViewer(rptViewer);
        rptViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        rptViewer.ShowReportBody = true;
        rptViewer.ReportRefresh += rptViewer_ReportRefresh;

        var v = rptViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters().Select(p => new ReportParameter(p.Name, p.Values.ToArray()));
        rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(v);
        rptViewer.AsyncRendering = false;
        rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a better answer but until then, I hide the parameters panel (and might even hide the collapsed bar through CSS) and simulate a click on the button.
It's not ideal, but it works.

In the code behind :

```
rptViewer.PromptAreaCollapsed = true;
```

In the ASPX script header :

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    var btnSubmit = $("#<%=rptViewer.ClientID%> :submit");
    btnSubmit.trigger("click");
});
```